# UIKit Dynamics: Calculating pushDirection Needed for UIPushBehavior

Tags: ios7, uikit

I'd like to use `UIPushBehavior` to give a physically realistic animation of a view across the screen. But to do this, I need to be be able to calculated the magnitude of the push needed in the `CGVector` in the `pushDirection` property of `UIPushBehavior`.

Basically, I know the size of the view, the amount of time, and the distance I'd like it to travel. Is there a way to use the `UIKit` Newton definition and a `UIDynamicItemBehavior` with resistance to calculate exactly the magnitude need to move a view a specific distance in a specific amount of time?

Comment: I don't have much idea about it,resistance is one property available in UIDynamicItemBehavior instance ,Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a pan gesture, you can do this:

```
if ( gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
{
     CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView:gestureRecognizer.view.superview];
     CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x) + (velocity.y * velocity.y));

     myPushBehavior = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[gestureRecognizer.view]
                                                         mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];
     myPushBehavior.pushDirection = CGVectorMake((velocity.x / 10) , (velocity.y / 10));
     myPushBehavior.magnitude = magnitude;
}
```

Courtesy of [Tony Dahbura's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/71828/uikit-dynamics-tutorial-tossing-views).

Comment: Sadly this answer is 2 years after I asked the question, and I no longer am working in the project so I can't test the example code to mark it as correct or not.

But thanks for adding the answer anyway; hopefully it can help someone else!

Comment: In the pushDirection, you use a value to divide by 10.  What is 10 in relationship to here?  I have found that avoiding magnitude works better for me, as I use a combination of the size of the view being pushed around and changing that 10 number something else that works with the size of the view being pushed around.  I don't know the relationship of these number sadly, thus I result to trial and error to find something that feels natural.